# ¿Cómo puedo poner cada imagen en una página diferente con la biblioteca itextpdf?

Tags: android, kotlin, imagen, itext, aplicación-movil

Estoy usando la biblioteca ItextPDF para crear PDF a partir de imágenes, esta es mi función quien hace todo el trabajo:

```
private fun pdf(nombre: String, tamanio: PageSize, listaDeURIs: List<Uri>) {
    Log.d("PDF", "Nombre de archivo PDF: ${obtenerNombreUnico(nombre)}")

    // Directorio donde se almacenará el archivo PDF
    val outputPdfDir = documentsDirectory
    outputPdfDir.mkdirs()// Crea el directorio si no existe

    // Ruta completa del archivo PDF de salida
    val outputPdfFilePath = File(outputPdfDir, obtenerNombreUnico(nombre))
    Log.d("PDF", "Establezco salida $outputPdfFilePath")

    // Crear un nuevo documento PDF
    val pdfWriter = PdfWriter(outputPdfFilePath)
    val pdfDocument = PdfDocument(pdfWriter)
    pdfDocument.defaultPageSize = tamanio

    val document = Document(pdfDocument)

    for (uri in listaDeURIs) {
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.path)

        // Convertir la imagen en un array de bytes
        val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream)
        val byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()

        // Crear una imagen a partir del array de bytes
        val imageData = ImageDataFactory.create(byteArray)
        val image = Image(imageData)

        val newPage = pdfDocument.addNewPage(tamanio)

        //redimensiona la imagen a la pagina
        image.scaleToFit(newPage.pageSize.width, newPage.pageSize.height)

        //margen superior e izquierdo a 0
        image.setFixedPosition(0f, 0f)

        // Agrega la imagen al documento PDF
        document.add(image)
    }

    //Cierro el documento
    document.close()

    // Muestra un mensaje de éxito
    Toast.makeText(this, "PDF creado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    Log.d("PDF", "PDF creado en ${outputPdfFilePath.absolutePath}")

    // Navega de vuelta a la actividad principal
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()

    Toast.makeText(this, "PDF creado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Con ese código lo que obtengo es la misma cantidad de hojas en el PDF que la cantidad de imágenes en la lista, pero cuando coloco las imágenes en el PDF, todas se colocan una encima de la otra en la primera página. Me gustaría poder tener cada imagen en una página dedicada.